# Is it possible to have swagger ui use the API Blueprint spec?

Tags: node.js, swagger-ui, apiblueprint

I am developing on node.js and currently using aglio to preview my API Blueprint markdown files. Everything is good except that I cannot test the API. I like how http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com/ has a way to test the api, just wondering if swagger had a way to accept the api blueprint spec?

I tried looking around the swagger docs, but I feel that maybe I'm missing it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe Swagger UI accepts API Blueprints. However, you can open a free account at http://apiary.io and paste in your API Blueprint to the editor. It will give you a mock server, code samples in different languages, a console to interact with the mock API and a traffic inspector. You can watch mock server traffic and route production traffic through it as well. That may be what you are looking for.